# AWS Sagemaker Notebook Not working ,how can i solve the issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

The code failed because of a fatal error:
Error sending http request and maximum retry encountered..

Some things to try:
a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources for Jupyter to create a Spark context.
b) Contact your Jupyter administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured correctly.
c) Restart the kernel.

Note: There are no such logs on cloudwatch to figureout the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbvBw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to run Spark queries? If not, you can use the Python kernel, or any kernel other than Sparkmagic and proceed with your work.

If not, see [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/) and the [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-lifecycle-config-emr.html) to use Spark with notebook instances